# Dictionary Issue in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all, sorry for the vague title as I wasn't sure what to call it.

Here is the issue I'm having, I'm creating a dict structure like so:

```
requestDict["001"]["request"] = "GET / HTTP..."

requestDict["001"]["response"] = "HTTP 1.1 OK..."
```

etc.

But this isn't working

```
def fiddler_convert(filename):
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "r")

requestDict = {}

for name in archive.namelist():
    if name.find(".txt") != -1: 
        requestNum = (name.split("_")[0]).split("/")[1]
        requestDict[requestNum] = {}

        if name.find("_c.txt"):
            requestDict[requestNum]["request"] = archive.read(name)
        elif name.find("_s.txt"):
            requestDict[requestNum]["response"] = archive.read(name)
        else:
            print "wat"

for key, value in requestDict:
    print key + ":" + value

archive.close()
```

I get an error of `for key, value in requestDict:`
`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Why is this? The type of each `value` is just a string ie "001", "002", etc.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas? The input is all good (ie. `requestNum` variable is set correct to "001" and `archive.read(name)` is good).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values returned by a dictionary iterator are keys, not tuples `(key, value)`. Consider using `items()`, or `iteritems()` instead.

Comment: Huh, yea that worked - I think I need too read a bit more into python. Thanks, will mark as answer when I can.